# Heroku Login Multi-Factor Authentication mfa_required error (without opening a browser)

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

When using Heroku Multi-Factor Authentication, is there any way to login via the console **without** opening the browser?

```
ubuntu:~/environment $ heroku login -i
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email [hello@gmail.com]: 
Password: ****************
 ›   Error: Your account has MFA enabled; API requests using basic authentication with email and password are not supported. Please 
 ›   generate an authorization token for API access. 
 ›
 ›   Error ID: mfa_required
```

Comment: Just use the API Key as password: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70045795/9095551

Answer (score 3):

For multi-factor authentication enabled heroku account,  If you can get the API key then there is a simpler way to sign in via CLI. type -> heroku login -i

enter the email id associated with your heroku account and for password you must enter the API key that you got from the account settings page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Basically, to set this up what you want to do is:

1. Login to Heroku and create an API Token under "Account settings". (You said "without opening a browser", and I'm assuming you mean 'How to authenticate from the command-line'. To set this up you *will* need to open a browser ... once ;)
2. In your local machine's home directory, check to see if you already have a file called `.netrc`. If not, simply create one like so -- `touch ~/.netrc`.
3. From there you'll want to append the following to that file (and save):

```
machine api.heroku.com
 login <your-email-goes-here>
 password <the-api-token-goes-here>
machine git.heroku.com
 login <your-email-goes-here>
 password <the-api-token-goes-here>
```

4. If you just created the `.netrc` file you'll want to `chmod 600 .netrc` to give it necessary permissions.
5. At this point, you can try the command `heroku auth:whoami` and hopefully see your user e-mail printed back to you.

FWIW, Heroku does have *some* docs covering this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication), but to be honest, the docs are rather disjointed and I would think unhelpful to someone that's never done something like this before, which is why I tried to go step-by-step.

I hope this is what you wanted and / or someone finds this helpful :)

Comment: I did exactly this but it didn't work. I got the following error:
`Invalid credentials provided.

Error ID: unauthorized`