# Failed to login heroku by MFA

Tags: heroku

I tried to login on heroku, but I was required to enter code generated by authenticator app, but I have no the authenticator app. I tried heroku login -i, but it says

```
"Error: Your account has MFA enabled; API requests using basic authentication with email 
 ›   and password are not supported. Please generate an authorization token for API access."
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You must enable [Multi-Factor Authentication](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multi-factor-authentication) and set up your preferred [MFA option](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multi-factor-authentication#mfa-verification-methods).

One of the options is to install Google Authenticator and configure it to access Heroku: after login (on the browser) you need to provide the code displayed in the Google Authentication application.

**Login via Command Line**

The approach is still the same but you need to use the API Key as the password

```
% heroku login -i
heroku: Enter your login credentials. 
Email [my email address]:  
Password: ************************************. # enter API Key here.  
Logged in as [my email address]
```

To create the API Token go to Heroku Dashboard -> Account

[image]

Comment: I don't know my API Key either....

Comment: You need to generate one, then you can copy and use it

Comment: How can I generate it even I can't log in?

Comment: You cannot login via the browser too?

Comment: yes, it still requires to enter code generated by authenticator app, but I have no the authenticator app.

Comment: You must have enabled it sometime ago (I use Authy for example), but if you don't remember or you did not enable it the only option is to send a ticket to Heroku support